# performance concern - update null column based on row_num

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm populating a 20-column table, and I want to divide & label the records by 60 million. So the value  of col20 for 1-60,000,000 records will be '1', 61,000,000-120,000,000 records will be '2', etc.

I'm taking following steps:

1. populating 19 columns, leave col20 as null
2. create temp table, store all records
3. delete all from table
4. ```
   insert into table
   select *, 1 + FLOOR( (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by col1) - 1)/60000000 ) as col20
   from temp
   ```

I dont really familiar with Snowflake performance, I just feel that delete all & re-insert looks stupid and not efficient.  Is there another way to achieve this? Or maybe its not an issue in snowflake in terms of performance?

updates: I should mean this - the table doesnt have primary key/unique key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do an UPDATE on col20 after the data is loaded using the same logic you described above. Is there any reason why update cannot be done?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I may did it wrong but I got error "Analytic function not allowed as target of UPDATE." do you know why?
```
update table
set col20 = 1 + FLOOR( (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by col1) - 1)/60000000 ) 
```

Comment: oh I should mean this: this table doesnt have primary key/unique key.